# Binary words starting with arbitrarily long squares

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

What is the measure of the following set of infinite binary words?

> $S=\{w\in\{0,1\}^\omega\ \text{such that},\ \text{for every}\ N\in\mathbb{N},\, w\ \text{has a prefix of the form}\ pp\ \text{with}\  |p|\ge N \}$.

Comment: What context does this problem arise in?

Comment: I am trying to understand what can be reasonably taken as the domain of the map $\mathcal{B}$ described in this other question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/377105/167834 (although the link may be not completely obvious, it is not too difficult to see that this question here is basic for the other one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any given $p\in\{0,1\}^*$ (finite word), the measure of the set of $w\in\{0,1\}^\omega$ starting with $pp$ is $2^{-2|p|}$.  So, summing over all the $p$ with $|p|=L$ (there are $2^L$ of them), given $L\in\mathbb{N}$, the measure of the set $S_L$ of $w\in\{0,1\}^\omega$ starting with $pp$ for some $p$ with $|p|=L$ is $2^{-L}$.  So the measure of $\bigcup_{L=N}^{+\infty} S_L$ is $\leq \sum_{L=N}^{+\infty} 2^{-L} = 2^{1-N}$, and the measure of $S = \bigcap_{N=0}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{L=N}^{+\infty} S_L$ is $0$.